# SQL Exception Code

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have been catching the SQL exception codes in C# using:

```
 catch (SqlException x)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(x.Message.ToString());
            Program.MyLogFile("SQL Upload Failed SQL Exception     ", x.ErrorCode.ToString() +" ", today);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message.ToString());
            Program.MyLogFile("SQL Upload Failed All Exeption    ", ex.Message.ToString() + " ", today);
            email();
        }
```

It gives me the following number in the text file. How can I tell what it means?

***Error Code: -2146232060***
I am using SQL 2012

Comment: You should consider logging the exception message in addition to the error code.

Comment: I already do that but Only the SQL Exception shows up in the log file.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're logging the wrong thing. The `Number` property would be far more useful, because that maps directly to the SQL Server error numbers that can easily be looked up.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using the SqlException.Number Property as shown here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx

Also this would give better understanding of the error message if  you query this in SQL Server if you want to work with one particular error code and do something:

```
SELECT * FROM sysmessages
```

If you look at error:104 from the above query and then:
Example If theres an error with Union and Order By in sql:

```
catch (SqlException e)
{
   switch (e.Number)
   {
      case 104:
         // Do something.
         break;
      default:
     throw;
   }
 }
```

Comment: Could you give some reasons why? This is a Link-only answer.

Comment: Good enough. Thank you